# How to remove all of the data in a table using Django

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I have two questions:

1. How do I delete a table in Django?
2. How do I remove all the data in the table?

This is my code, which is not successful:

```
Reporter.objects.delete()
```

Comment: From CLI: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6485106/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-clear-a-database-in-django

Comment: `python manage.py flush`, this will clean all the data from the database, but will not delete the tables

Answer (score 217, accepted):

Inside a manager:

```
def delete_everything(self):
    Reporter.objects.all().delete()

def drop_table(self):
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    table_name = self.model._meta.db_table
    sql = "DROP TABLE %s;" % (table_name, )
    cursor.execute(sql)
```

Comment: Also, if you're the delete_everything() method, beware of this bug: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/16426

Comment: While this answers the first question, it doesn't handle the second question. I would use `'DELETE FROM %s' % (table_name, )` for that bit, leaving the table empty but intact.

Answer (score 150):

As per the latest [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/queries/#deleting-objects), the correct method to call would be:

```
Reporter.objects.all().delete()
```

Comment: Yes but this gets killed if you have many records in the table. so I had to do it like:   for x in MyTable.objects.all().iterator(): x.delete()

Comment: @max Note however that with this, the instance's `delete` method is called, while with the `delete` call on the `QuerySet` it isn't.

Answer (score 52):

If you want to remove all the data from all your tables, you might want to try the command `python manage.py flush`. This will delete all of the data in your tables, but the tables themselves will still exist.

See more here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/django-admin/

Comment: Would have been helpful for you to mention that it also removes your superuser

Comment: He did say "all the data from all your tables", which should indicate that it's a very destructive operation.

Comment: The User table is in the same database as "your" tables. You should now that before using an operation like that.

Comment: Author asekd how to delete all data in table NOT how to flush all data in all tables.

Answer (score 42):

Using shell,

1) For Deleting the table:

```
python manage.py dbshell
>> DROP TABLE {app_name}_{model_name}
```

2) For removing all data from table:

```
python manage.py shell
>> from {app_name}.models import {model_name}
>> {model_name}.objects.all().delete()
```

Comment: option 1) needs a closing semicolon `>> DROP TABLE {app_name}_{model_name};`, also helpful to use `>> .tables` before to check names of tables.

Comment: no2 is the easiest way I found

Answer (score 6):

Django 1.11 delete all objects from a database table -

```
Entry.objects.all().delete()  ## Entry being Model Name.
```

Refer the Official Django documentation here as quoted below - 
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/queries/#deleting-objects

Note that delete() is the only QuerySet method that is not exposed on a Manager itself. This is a safety mechanism to prevent you from accidentally requesting Entry.objects.delete(), and deleting all the entries. If you do want to delete all the objects, then you have to explicitly request a complete query set:

I myself tried the code snippet seen below within my `somefilename.py`

```
    # for deleting model objects
    from django.db import connection
    def del_model_4(self):
        with connection.schema_editor() as schema_editor:
            schema_editor.delete_model(model_4)
```

and within my `views.py` i have a view that simply renders a html page ...

```
  def data_del_4(request):
      obj = calc_2() ## 
      obj.del_model_4()
      return render(request, 'dc_dash/data_del_4.html') ##
```

it ended deleting all entries from - model == model_4 , but now i get to see a Error screen within Admin console when i try to asceratin that all objects of model_4 have been deleted ...

```
ProgrammingError at /admin/dc_dash/model_4/
relation "dc_dash_model_4" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT COUNT(*) AS "__count" FROM "dc_dash_model_4"
```

Do consider that - if we do not go to the ADMIN Console and try and see objects of the model - which have been already deleted - the Django app works just as intended.

[django admin screencapture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/majXC.png)

Answer (score 5):

Use this syntax to delete the rows also to redirect to the homepage (To avoid page load errors) :

```
def delete_all(self):
  Reporter.objects.all().delete()
  return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
```

Answer (score 4):

I know the question is for a long time ago, but just for the record, because this saved me:

```py
python manage.py flush
```

The above will delete all the data on your database (PostgreSQL in my case). Even the superuser.

If you want to delete all the rows of a specific table, then:

```py
python manage.py shell
>> from app.models import SomeTable
>> SomeTable.objects.all().delete()
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the Django-Truncate library to delete all data of a table without destroying the table structure.

Example:

1. First, install django-turncate using your terminal/command line:

```sh
pip install django-truncate
```

2. Add "django_truncate" to your INSTALLED_APPS in the `settings.py` file:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    'django_truncate',
]
```

3. Use this command in your terminal to delete all data of the table from the app.

```sh
python manage.py truncate --apps app_name --models table_name
```

Comment: My google search showed me `python manage.py truncate --apps app_name --models table_name.` and I excitedly clicked to give you an upvote them saw this... super disappointing.  Gave you n upvote anyway though

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of ways:

To delete it directly:

```
SomeModel.objects.filter(id=id).delete()
```

To delete it from an instance:

```
instance1 = SomeModel.objects.get(id=id)
instance1.delete()
```

// don't use same name

Answer (score -4):

Actually, I un-register the model (the table data that I want to delete) from the admin.py. Then I migrate.

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
python runserver
```

Then I register the model in the admin.py and do migration again. :) Now, the table is empty. This might not be a professional answer, but it helped me.