# What is the easiest way to clear a database from the CLI with manage.py in Django?

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-1.3

I am using Django to build a website with MySQL. Now as I am learning so I need to change the Model very often so I want that all tables get cleared and new table get created.

But `syncdb` doesn't touch existing tables. Is there any  better way to handle this problem?

Answer (score 212, accepted):

If you don't care about data:

Best way would be to drop the database and run `syncdb` again. Or you can run:

For Django >= 1.5

```
python manage.py flush
```

For Django < 1.5

```
python manage.py reset appname
```

(you can add `--no-input` to the end of the command for it to skip the interactive prompt.)

If you do care about data:

From the docs:

> syncdb will only create tables for
>   models which have not yet been
>   installed. It will never issue ALTER
>   TABLE statements to match changes made
>   to a model class after installation.
>   Changes to model classes and database
>   schemas often involve some form of
>   ambiguity and, in those cases, Django
>   would have to guess at the correct
>   changes to make. There is a risk that
>   critical data would be lost in the
>   process.
>
> If you have made changes to a model
>   and wish to alter the database tables
>   to match, use the sql command to
>   display the new SQL structure and
>   compare that to your existing table
>   schema to work out the changes.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/

Reference: FAQ - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/faq/models/#if-i-make-changes-to-a-model-how-do-i-update-the-database

People also recommend South ( http://south.aeracode.org/docs/about.html#key-features ), but I haven't tried it.

Comment: South is really, really good for automatically handling migrations. Takes a bit of getting used to, but it saves a lot of hassle dropping and recreating databases during development, and is a must-have once your site is live and you need to alter the db structure while you have precious data in it.

Comment: **RESET COMMAND DEPRECIATED**. In Django 1.5 the command has been updated to `flush`. try using `python manage.py flush` or `python manage.py flush --noinput` to skip the interactive prompt.

Comment: **South has been deprecated**. Refer [here](https://south.aeracode.org/). And the link you've given here is broken.

Comment: It looks like the command is now `django-admin flush` according to the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/django-admin/#flush)

Answer (score 6):

Using [Django Extensions](https://github.com/django-extensions/django-extensions), running:

```
./manage.py reset_db
```

Will clear the database tables, then running:

```
./manage.py syncdb
```

Will recreate them (south may ask you to migrate things).

Comment: @becko execute this first : pip install django-extensions

Answer (score 4):

I think Django [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#flush) explicitly mention that if the intent is to start from an empty DB again (which seems to be OP's intent), then just drop and re-create the database and re-run `migrate` (instead of using `flush`):

> If you would rather start from an empty database and re-run all
>   migrations, you should drop and recreate the database and then run
>   migrate instead.

So for OP's case, we just need to:

1. Drop the database from MySQL
2. Recreate the database
3. Run `python manage.py migrate`

Comment: It would be useful to add commands for steps 1 and 2.

Comment: @Floella those commands need to be run directly on database - so, outside the scope of Django. If you are asking how to drop/create the database on MySQL, those are usual SQL: `DROP DATABASE <name>` and `CREATE DATABASE <name>`

Answer (score 0):

Quickest (drops and creates all tables including data):

```
./manage.py reset appname | ./manage.py dbshell
```

Caution:

- Might not work on Windows correctly.
- Might keep some old tables in the db

Comment: `reset` already runs the SQL, so no need to pipe to `dbshell`. If you use the `sqlreset` command, then that would just print out the SQL, which you could pipe to the shell for execution, but it's an unnecessary step.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Django-Truncate library to delete all data of a table without destroying the table structure.

Example:

1. First, install django-turncate using your terminal/command line:

```sh
pip install django-truncate
```

2. Add "django_truncate" to your INSTALLED_APPS in the `settings.py` file:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    'django_truncate',
]
```

3. Use this command in your terminal to delete all data of the table from the app.

```sh
python manage.py truncate --apps app_name --models table_name
```