# Django table TRUNCATE based on DB type in view

Tags: django

What is the fastest way to truncate a table in the Django ORM based on the database type in a view?  I know you can do this for example

```
Books.objects.all().delete()
```

but with tables containing millions of rows it is very slow. I know it is also possible to use the cursor and some custom SQL

```
from django.db import connection
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute("TRUNCATE TABLE `books`")
```

However, the TRUNCATE command does not work with SQLite. And if the database moves to another db type, I need to account for that.

Any ideas?  Would it be easier to just drop the table and recreate in my view?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4532681/how-to-remove-all-of-the-data-in-a-table-using-django || http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2988997/how-do-i-truncate-table-using-django-orm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Django's `.delete()` method is indeed very slow, as it loads the IDs of each object being deleted so that a `post_save` signal can be emitted.

This means that a simple `connection.execute("DELTE FROM foo")` will be significantly faster than `Foo.objects.delete()`.

If that's still too slow, a truncate or drop+recreate is definitely the way to go. You can get the SQL used to create a table with: `output, references = connection.creation.sql_create_model(model, style)`, where `style = django.core.management.color_style()` (this is taken from https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/core/management/sql.py#L14).

Comment: Glad I could help :) NOW, my $0.02 on using SQLite: *if* you are *only* using it during development (ie, because it's simpler than running a "full" database like Postgres or MySQL), I would suggest not doing that. I love SQLite, and used to use it heavily in development, but eventually realized that I was spending more time maintaining SQLite compatibility than it saved me, so now I simply use Postgres everywhere, and I'm happier for it. Of course, there are good reasons to ignore what I'm saying. Just my $0.02.

Comment: Good point! Yes, I am using SQLite for development. However, I will take your advice and install something more robust like Postgres.  Thanks again!

Comment: No problem! And, ya — Postgres in development isn't right for *everyone*, just make sure you're being sensible about it, and considering the time you're spending on supporting SQLite versus the time it takes to setup Postgres.