# Mysql / Django - Begin auto increment to 1

Tags: mysql, database, django

I have a django script which loads data, the beginning of the script deletes all datas in database.
So when I execute 1st time this script, the auto increment primary keys begin to 1 to 15 (if 15 objects) and if I want to reload data, I reexecute the script.
My issue is when I execute it again, pks numbers begin to 16 (for 2nd launch), I would like each time auto_increment begins to 1, is it possible whitout regenerating tables structure each time ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You could use [ALTER TABLE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/alter-table.html), but I'm not sure that is that much better than just regenerating the schema.

```
ALTER TABLE table AUTO_INCREMENT = 1;
```

Answer (score 2):

When you delete rows from the database, you're not really:

1. Freeing up the disk space
2. Resetting the auto_increment values as you've noticed.

As such, it might actually be a better idea to drop the table and re-create it as required. Failing that you can use just either:

1. [`TRUNCATE <table name>;`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/truncate-table.html) (Depending on your storage engine, this will actually drop/re-create as mentioned above for you.)
2. `ALTER TABLE <table name> SET AUTO_INCREMENT = X;`

Of these, I'd recommend using the truncate approach.

Comment: Thanks, truncate seems the good solution, but I need to run it with django orm engine.
I found this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2988997/how-do-i-truncate-table-using-django-orm